# Python: interactively investigating a large array in a navigable window

Tags: python, arrays, display

I would like to be able to interactively investigate a 2-d array in python, like I can do in **Matlab** or **ImageJ**. For instance, I can bring up the following in **ImageJ**:

**interactively investigating array:**

[image]

Is there a way to do this with python? I know I can print the full or partial array to the python window, but that doesn't allow interactive scrolling through the array, as Matlab does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the programming language and the IDE. MATLAB forces one and only one IDE on you which is where this complication comes from. In Python (or most other real programming languages) there are numerous different IDEs to choose from which have different features / strengths and weaknesses.

In my opinion both [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/) are pretty close to MATLAB's IDE and both have navigable array viewing table widgets. [Rodeo](https://www.yhat.com/products/rodeo) also has this but is more simple and clean looking.

Also, [Jupyter Notebooks](http://jupyter.org) are pretty cool.  Play around with some different IDEs and see what you like best and makes you the most productive!

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the process of experimenting with the various IDE options, which should help.  I have accepted your answer as a solution.  I was hoping that there was some equivalent of the pyplot .imshow that I could call natively from the code, which would display the array values instead of an image representing the array.  For most of my use cases, I don't otherwise need an IDE, and I greatly prefer coding with Vim.

Comment: Ah okay. When you mentioned MATLAB I figured you were referring to an IDE feature. In that case you could look to the GUI libraries in Python for table widgets. I've made these sorts of things in [PyQT](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro). I guess you could create your own widget for this and re use it for interactively